# How to set orientation for each scene in xCode SpriteKit?

Tags: xcode, orientation, landscape, portrait

I'm working on a basic game with 3 scenes. The first is the menu (landscaped). From that I choose from sprites between two versions of the game: first is with only portrait (and upside down) orientations, and the other is landscape left or right. In `ViewController` I use `viewWillLayoutSubviews`. (I don't know if it's relevant now).

Is it possible to allow only portrait or landscape orientation for different scenes?

Comment: check this link http://www.johnandrewtorres.com/uncategorized/sprite-kit-portrait-landscape-orientation/

Comment: I've already found this but it does not say anything about the connection of scenes and view controllers or setting a scene to be either portrait or landscape oriented.